# The for structure show the element in JsonArray from the 465 not from 0... why

Tags: java, arrays

The program i wanna create, read a file name from a data.Json and then rename the file in a specific directory. 
I'm trying to read a JsonArray and get a key, it works but the array starts from 461 or other index not from 0.
If i delete the last line of my code it start from 0. This is not a real problem because the last line of code is only a check develope information, but i don't know why this happens.
The array has 903 element.

```
FileReader reader= new FileReader("C:\\Users\\utente\\Desktop\\pictures\\data.json");
    JSONTokener tokenizer=new JSONTokener(reader); 
    JSONArray jsnArray= new JSONArray(tokenizer); 
    JSONObject obj=new JSONObject(); 
    File checkFile;

    for(int i=0; i<jsnArray.length();i++)
    {
        String nome;

        System.out.println("Iterazione Native "+i);// only check point
        obj=jsnArray.getJSONObject(i);
        String nomeFile= obj.getString("url");
        nomeFile=nomeFile.replace("9/", "!");
        nomeFile=nomeFile.replace("8/", "!");
        nomeFile=nomeFile.substring(nomeFile.indexOf("!")+1,nomeFile.indexOf("?") );
        System.out.println(i + " " +nomeFile);
        nome=("C:\\Users\\utente\\Desktop\\pictures\\diario_files\\"+nomeFile);
        System.out.println(i+ " "+nome);// if i delete this line it works printing from index 0

    }


}
```

}

Comment: when you say it doesn't work, what happens? Is there an exception? Bad output?

Comment: It print the name of file inside the JSON Array from index 465, or other, not from index 0. If i delete the last line of code System.out.println(i+ " "+nome); it works so start from index 0.

Comment: Can you print out the object at index 0? I suspect it doesn't contain  a `url` attribute so you end up with a `null` nomeFile.

Comment: Note that if any url does not have a question mark in it, you'll get a `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` in your last `nomeFile.substring()` call. Are you getting any exceptions?

Comment: No exceptions. This is the index 0 {"date":"2020-04-18 10:52:33","href":"https://www.facebook.com/GelaStories/photos/a.327880747313313/2465566523544714/?type=3","tag":"","title":"SICILE - GELA - 1943 Photos : J R Eyerman - LIFE Collections Â©","url":"https://scontent-fco1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/93611603_2465566526878047_5340253527144923136_n.jpg?_nc_cat=104&_nc_sid=2d5d41&_nc_ohc=iLW7ISCGvFYAX9yDWgK&_nc_ht=scontent-fco1-1.xx&oh=4a8bb7ef6161aa08f866f93538f66762&oe=5EC53F8E"}